# Fetch image from server and render it in

Tags: ruby, rubymotion, rubymotion-promotion

I want to fetch image from the server, save it locally and and display when user opens the show page - with Rubymotion.

I am using AFMotion to fetch the image url as follows.
[image]

In my show screen I can get the image url with news.image_url. My doubt is how do i pass this to the layout file where I can add some styles to it like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my own question. This is what i have done.

[image]

In the on_load method of the show news page, I pass the image url and set the remote_image for the UIImageView to the image url passed.

[image]

I got the solution from the red potion documentation. http://docs.redpotion.org/en/latest/cookbook/networking/